# Reference for optimization on Riemannian manifolds

Tags: reference-request, optimization, riemannian-geometry

Can anyone recommend me a fairly good textbook on optimization on manifolds?
I only managed to find this: [Convex Functions and Optimization Methods on Riemannian Manifolds](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=uX_rCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=riemannian%20optimization%20methods&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQy7b6hs_nAhU1rHEKHRSqC-wQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=riemannian%20optimization%20methods&f=false)

It seems a bit old, nothing against it obviously the content seems ok to me, but maybe there's something more recent out there.

Ideally I'd like something like [Numerical Optimization
By Jorge Nocedal, Stephen Wright](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VbHYoSyelFcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=numerical%20optimization&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbztvk9dDnAhWNecAKHTQvBUsQ6AEIQDAC#v=onepage&q=numerical%20optimization&f=false) but translated on manifolds.

But any reference you can suggest in general is fine.

Answer (score 2):

The book [Optimization Algorithms on Matrix Manifolds](https://press.princeton.edu/absil), by P.-A. Absil, R. Mahoney, and Rodolphe Sepulchre is from 2007. It is significantly more challenging and less nuts and bolts oriented than :Numerical Optimization", byJorge Nocedal, Stephen Wright.

Nicolas Boumal, co-developer of the [Manopt](https://www.manopt.org/) Matlab tool­box for opti­mization on manifolds, is finishing up a draft of a book "An introduction to optimization on smooth manifolds". I think it may be more mathematically accessible and concrete than "Optimization Algorithms on Matrix Manifolds".

Per http://web.math.princeton.edu/~nboumal/#book

> To be available soonish: a first draft of my introductory lecture
>   notes for optimization on smooth manifolds. In the meantime, feel free
>   to reach out by e-mail to ask for a private PDF copy.

Comment: Thanks Mark -- the book is now available: I'll post it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Mark L. Stone's answer, I wrote a textbook for Riemannian optimization which may address the needs you describe:

*An introduction to optimization on smooth manifolds*

http://www.nicolasboumal.net/book

It does not assume any prerequisites in geometry. It addresses certain aspects of practical importance for numerical implementations, such as numerical pitfalls and recommended parameter values.

Comment: Bitchin' book!!